# Reactjs Modificar un array

Tags: reactjs, crud

tengo un problema, con un crud que estoy haciendo, con reactjs, cuando le doy modificar me envia el dato al input, pero cuando le doy al boton enviar, se me actualiza la pagina y no el array :( que estoy haciendo mal. Es decir me elimina el array, al darle modificar me envia el valor al input pero no me actualiza e.e creo que estoy haciendo mal la funcion clickmodificar o handlesubmit? please e.e tambien tengo un error que cuando llega a dos o mas de valor en el indice del array se me actualiza o.o, consejos?

```
       class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      nombre:'',
      apellido: '',
      active: 0,
      index: '',
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    let index = this.state.index;
    let lista = this.state.list;
    if(this.state.active === 0){
      lista.push({nombre:this.state.nombre,apellido:this.state.apellido})
      this.setState({
          nombre:'',
          apellido:'',
      })
    }else{
      lista[index].nombre = this.state.nombre
      lista[index].apellido = this.state.apellido
      this.setState({
        list:lista,
        active: 0
      })
    }



    e.preventDefault();
  }

  handleDestroy = (value)=> {

    let remove = this.state.list;
    remove.splice(value, 1);
    this.setState({
      list:remove
    })
 }
 clickModificar = (value) =>{
  let modificar = this.state.list[value];
  this.setState({
    nombre: modificar.nombre,
    apellido: modificar.apellido,
    active: 1,
    index: modificar,

  })

 }
  render(){
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Formulario 
              nombre={this.state.nombre} 
              apellido={this.state.apellido} 
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              />
            <Tables listado={this.state.list} clickDestroy={this.handleDestroy} clickModificar={this.clickModificar}/>

        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

[image: aqui el mini formulario]

Answer (score 0):

Listo resolvi lo que pasaba es que no estaba pasando el indice del array si no los objetos directamente en la funcion de HandleSubmit el cual quedo asi.

```
handleSubmit(e){
    var lista = this.state.list
    var index = this.state.index
    if(this.state.active === 0){
      lista.push({nombre:this.state.nombre,apellido:this.state.apellido})
      this.setState({
          nombre:'',
          apellido:'',
      })
    }else{
      var value = lista.indexOf(index)
      lista[value].nombre = this.state.nombre
      lista[value].apellido = this.state.apellido

      this.setState({
        list:lista,
        nombre:'',
        apellido: '',
        active:0,
        index:''
      })


    }

    e.preventDefault();
  }
```